# Update object from a list without losing the array position

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, bloc, cubit

I need to update an object in a dart array, I don't want to remove it and add it again, I just need to update it so that it doesn't lose its position in the array.
I'm removing and adding, so it creates another index, I need to replace it without losing the array position.

I'm removing and adding, so it creates another index, I need to replace it without losing the array position.

Comment: If you're mutating an object that's already in a `List`, just mutate it.  If you want to replace an element of a `List`, reassign the `List` element: `yourList[index] = NewObject();`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to identify the object's index in the list. This will allow you to modify it without losing its position on the list.

for example:

```
// Sample array of objects
List<MyObject> myArray = [
  MyObject('Object 1'),
  MyObject('Object 2'),
  MyObject('Object 3'),
];

// Function to update an object in the array
void updateObject(MyObject updatedObject, int index) {
  myArray[index] = updatedObject;
}

// Usage example
int indexToUpdate = 1; // Index of the object to update
MyObject updatedObject = MyObject('Updated Object'); // New instance of the updated object
updateObject(updatedObject, indexToUpdate); // Update the object at the specified index

// Print the updated array
print(myArray);
```